# Python: Recursive One-Dimensional Game (Leap Current Index (N) Times Repeatedly to the Right or Left Until Last Index of the List Found)

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

Consider this list of input:

```
Index:       0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8

Input List:  1, 2, 6, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1
```

---

This is the first time I have ever used stack overflow to ask a question, so please excuse my lack of knowledge in terms of formatting and conciseness.

I have two functions `move_right()` and `move_left()` that move either right or left from the initial position of list. The variables `current_index` and the `current_element` updates each time the right or the left function is called.

Starting from the first element on my list `1` which has an index of `0` the `move_right()` function replaces and prints the current index by shifting to the right the number of current element times (1 in this case). The `move_right()` function call updates the `current_index = 1`. The next function call of `move_right()` changes the `current_index = 3` since we shifted the current element `2` times to the right. The positions that will be printed by the end of my recursive function is, if the `move_right()` function keeps returning true within the range of the list:

```
0, 1, 3, 6, 7
```

---

The `move_left()` function has the same algorithm as above, but in the opposite direction. Check out this code:

```
global game_board, start_position, end_postion, current_element, current_index, previous_index, repeated_index

game_board = input().split()

try:
        for index in range(len(game_board)):
                game_board[index] = int(game_board[index])
except ValueError:
        print ('Error: Invalid list of numbers!')
        sys.exit(1)

    previous_index = 0
    current_index = previous_index
    start_position = game_board[0]
    end_position = len(game_board)-1
    current_element = game_board[current_index]
    repeated_index = []

    def move_right():
            global current_index
            global current_element
            global previous_index
            global repeated_index
            # Track repeated indexes on seperate list
            repeated_index.append(current_index)
            current_element = game_board[current_index]
            right_sum = 0
            # Increment current element times to right 
            for right_sum in range(0, current_element):
                    right_sum += 1
            previous_index = right_sum
            current_index += right_sum
            right_sum = 0
            if (current_element == 0):
                    return False
            # Return true unless out of range (right direction)
            if (current_index <= end_position):
                    print(current_index, end = ' ')
                    return True
            else:
                    return False

    def move_left():
            global current_index
            global current_element
            global previous_index
            global current_new_index
            # Access to current new element
            current_new_index = current_index - previous_index
            current_element = game_board[current_new_index]
            left_sum = 0
            # Traverse in negative direction
            for left_sum in range(0, current_element):
                    left_sum += 1
            previous_index = current_new_index
            current_new_index -= left_sum
            left_sum = 0
            if (current_element == 0):
                    return False
            if (current_new_index < 0):
                    return False
            # Return true unless out of bounds (left direction)
            if (previous_index >= start_position):
                    print(current_new_index, end = ' ')
                    current_index = current_new_index
                    return True
            else:
                    return False
```

---

Now this recursive function for the `move_right()` function below traverses through the list until we exceed the range of list. By the order of precedence in an if condition using the logical `or` operator, the `move_left()` function gets called now since `move_right()` function is false. Now we move left inside our list to find a different route to the solution of reaching the final index or the end position of our list which is `8` in our case. This recursive function only moves once to the left, and then proceeds to move right as many times as possible until we reach the final number or we go out of bounds. Here is the recursive function and the output:

```
    def can_win(): 
            # Lost the game if no possible actions from current postion
            for repeat in repeated_index:
                    if (current_element <= 0 or current_index > end_position or repeat == current_index or current_index < 0):     
                            print('<br />', 'No more actions possible! You lost! (Either out of bounds, or landed on a zero number, or stepped on a repeated number, or entered a negative number)')
                            print('<br />', '<br />')
                            sys.exit(0)
            # Won the game if last postion found
            if (current_index == end_position):
                    print('<br />', 'Landed on the last number! You won!')
                    print('<br />', '<br />')
                    sys.exit(0)
            once = True
            # Move right or left until both functions return false
            if (move_right() or move_left() or once == True):
                    can_win()
                    once = False

if (current_element <= 0):
            print('<br />', 'You lost! (First number is either negative or zero!)')
            print('<br />', '<br />')
            sys.exit(0)
if (game_board):
            print('List of positions:', current_index, end = ' ')
            can_win()
```

---

```
Resulting Output: 0, 1, 3, 6, 7, 4, 6 (No more actions possible! You lost!)
```

Although the actual output should be:

```
Real Output: 0, 1, 3, 6, 7, 4, 2, 8 (Landed on the last number! You won!)
```

---

I can't think of any other alternative since the goal is to find a solution using a recursive function. The first course of action using this method obviously does not work:

```
if (move_right() or move_left() or once == True):
            can_win()
```

---

The next step would be to call `move_left()` function twice and then keep calling the `move_right()` function to find the last index. If there is a different set of numbers, then I need to keep calling the `move_left()` function as many times as possible to find the last number in any list of numbers. If I can traverse all the way till the end of the right direction for every possible move to the left, then I can print the correct output. If there is no possible solution, then the user in actuality loses the game. I would really appreciate if someone can help me with this problem! Let me know if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a recursive function with a parameter that keeps track of the path in pairs of index and last index, yield the indices in the path if the index reaches the end of the board, and avoid further recursion if the index is out of range, if the current tile is 0, or if the pair of the proposed next index and the current index is already part of the path:

```
def move(board, path=((0, None),)):
    index = path[-1][0]
    if index == len(board) - 1:
        yield [i for i, _ in path]
    if 0 <= index < len(board) and board[index]:
        for direction in 1, -1:
            new = index + board[index] * direction
            if (new, index) not in path:
                yield from move(board, path + ((new, index),))
```

so that the following test cases:

```
game_boards = [
    [1, 2, 6, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 7, 0],
    [1, 2, 3, 1, 10, 2, 10, 0],
    [1, 2, 3, 1, -1, 2, 10, 0],
    [1, 2, 6, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1],
    [3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 0], # the same index might be worth revisiting
    [3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4], # there could be valid paths beyond the end
    [2, 4, 3, 5]
]
for game_board in game_boards:
    print('%s => %s' % (game_board, list(move(game_board))))
```

will output:

```
[1, 2, 6, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1] => [[0, 1, 3, 6, 7, 4, 2, 8], [0, 1, 3, 6, 5, 7, 4, 2, 8]]
[1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 7, 0] => [[0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 5, 4, 8], [0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 8]]
[1, 2, 3, 1, 10, 2, 10, 0] => [[0, 1, 3, 2, 5, 7]]
[1, 2, 3, 1, -1, 2, 10, 0] => [[0, 1, 3, 4, 3, 2, 5, 7], [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7], [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 5, 7], [0, 1, 3, 2, 5, 7], [0, 1, 3, 2, 5, 3, 4, 5, 7]]
[1, 2, 6, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1] => [[0, 1, 3, 6, 7, 4, 2, 8], [0, 1, 3, 6, 5, 7, 4, 2, 8]]
[3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 0] => [[0, 3, 5, 3, 1, 4, 6], [0, 3, 1, 4, 6]]
[3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4] => [[0, 3, 6], [0, 3, 6, 2, 6]]
[2, 4, 3, 5] => []
```

EDIT: Since you now mentioned in the comments that you'd like the indices, rather than the moves, not to be repeated, I've modified the above solution to keep track of just the indices in the path instead:

```
def move(board, path=(0,)):
    index = path[-1]
    if index == len(board) - 1:
        yield path
    if 0 <= index < len(board) and board[index]:
        for direction in 1, -1:
            new = index + board[index] * direction
            if new not in path:
                yield from move(board, path + (new,))
```

so that given the same test cases as the first solution, this outputs:

```
[1, 2, 6, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1] => [(0, 1, 3, 6, 7, 4, 2, 8), (0, 1, 3, 6, 5, 7, 4, 2, 8)]
[1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 7, 0] => [(0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 8)]
[1, 2, 3, 1, 10, 2, 10, 0] => [(0, 1, 3, 2, 5, 7)]
[1, 2, 3, 1, -1, 2, 10, 0] => [(0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7), (0, 1, 3, 2, 5, 7)]
[1, 2, 6, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1] => [(0, 1, 3, 6, 7, 4, 2, 8), (0, 1, 3, 6, 5, 7, 4, 2, 8)]
[3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 0] => [(0, 3, 1, 4, 6)]
[3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4] => [(0, 3, 6)]
[2, 4, 3, 5] => []
```

Comment: Consider for example the following lists where the algorithm will be stuck in an infinite recursion loop: `[1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 7, 0]`, `[1, 2, 3, 1, 10, 2, 10, 0]`, `[1, 2, 3, 1, -1, 2, 10, 0]`.

Comment: Indeed I misunderstood the question. I've updated my solution accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: As far as I understand the OP the solution doesn't depend on any history (i.e. previous indices) but is completely determined by the current index. So it's not clear why it is necessary to keep track of `(current, previous)` pairs. Using the example `[3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 0]` the solution `[0, 3, 5, 3, 1, 4, 6]` is superfluous because starting from index `3` the solution is `[1, 4, 6]`. Otherwise, by the same logic, `[0, 3, 5, 3, 5, 3, 5, 3, ..., 1, 4, 6]` would be solutions as well (and there are infinitely many).

Comment: @a_guest I don't consider `[0, 3, 5, 3, 1, 4, 6]` superfluous because it offers a valid path using distinctly different moves (or edges, in terms of a graph), from 3 to 5, and from 5 to 3, than `[0, 3, 1, 4, 6]`. On the other hand, `[0, 3, 5, 3, 5, 3, 5, 3, ..., 1, 4, 6]` is certainly superfluous, since it's graphically the same as `[0, 3, 5, 3, 1, 4, 6]`, which is exactly the reason why I'm keeping tuples of (index, last index) in the path history, so that the same moves, as opposed to just the same tiles, aren't repeated.

Comment: I should have mentioned all the conditions before posting my question. The previous indices are not suppose to be repeated (else there will be an infinite recursive loop). If the user enters a zero (or a negative number for the sake of simplicity), then the recursion should stop and there are no more possible actions to win the game.

Comment: I used the most basic methods to find a solution to this problem without using any data structure concepts such as a linked list or a binary tree. I don't have much of programming experience as of yet, but I'm going to try all these codes to implement better solutions to future exercises. I have yet to try all the different answers that have been posted here and then I will get back to you guys (thank you all for that).

Comment: @csarth179 As demonstrated above, indices can be repeated without incurring an infinite recursion as long as the "moves" aren't repeated. But you're the OP so you make the rule here. I've updated my answer accordingly then. :-) Glad to be of help. Remember to accept the answer you find the most helpful (by clicking on the grey check mark next to the answer) once you've reviewed and tested all the answers.

Comment: @blhsing Sounds good, that's the least I can do. This input `[3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 0] => [[0, 3, 5, 3, 1, 4, 6]` certainly proves the case of avoiding an infinite recursion. That makes the problem more interesting if we were to not avoid repeated index. Also, the change of direction (moving left) can only occur once all the possible right moves have been attempted as the problem suggested. Seems like the solution to my problem has been found, this is a great place to improve your coding skills.

Comment: @blhsing I see, you got a point here. I didn't think of it in terms of moves. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

This basically resembles a binary tree with nodes being the indices in the list. Hence you can recursively build the corresponding path and prune the tree if the index is out of bounds of if a cycle is encountered. Note that this does not compare the various paths and hence does not necessarily return the shortest path (you could add this comparison though).

```
def move(step_sizes: list, path: tuple = (0,), direction: int = 1):
    '''
    step_sizes: The list to be traversed.
    path: Already visited indices.
    direction: Either +1 (right) or -1 (left).
    '''
    step = step_sizes[path[-1]] * direction
    new_pos = path[-1] + step
    if new_pos not in range(len(step_sizes)):  # Out of bounds.
        raise IndexError
    if new_pos in path:  # Contains a cycle.
        raise IndexError
    if new_pos == len(step_sizes) - 1:  # Solution found.
        return path + (new_pos,)
    try:
        return move(step_sizes, path + (new_pos,), -1)  # Move left.
    except IndexError:
        return move(step_sizes, path + (new_pos,), 1)  # Move right.


print(move(
    # Solution: r, r, l, r, r.
    # Contains a cycle: r, r, l, r, l.
    [1, 2, 3, 1, 10, 2, 10, 0],
    (0,),  # Start from first element.
    1      # Start with moving to the right.
))  # Solution: (0, 1, 3, 2, 5, 7).

print(move(
    [1, 2, 6, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1],
    (0,),
    1
))  # Solution: (0, 1, 3, 6, 5, 7, 4, 2, 8).
```

Some more test cases:

```
game_boards = [
    [1, 2, 6, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 7, 0],
    [1, 2, 3, 1, 10, 2, 10, 0],
    [1, 2, 3, 1, -1, 2, 10, 0],
    [1, 2, 6, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1],
    [3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 0],
    [3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4],
    [2, 4, 3, 5]
]
for game_board in game_boards:
    try:
        solution = move(game_board)
    except IndexError:
        solution = None
    print('%s => %s' % (game_board, solution))
```

With output:

```
[1, 2, 6, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1] => (0, 1, 3, 6, 5, 7, 4, 2, 8)
[1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 7, 0] => (0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 8)
[1, 2, 3, 1, 10, 2, 10, 0] => (0, 1, 3, 2, 5, 7)
[1, 2, 3, 1, -1, 2, 10, 0] => (0, 1, 3, 2, 5, 7)
[1, 2, 6, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1] => (0, 1, 3, 6, 5, 7, 4, 2, 8)
[3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 0] => (0, 3, 1, 4, 6)
[3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4] => (0, 3, 6)
[2, 4, 3, 5] => None
```

Note that the above function raises an `IndexError` if no path can be found. This can be changed to return `None` instead:

```
def move(step_sizes: list, path: tuple = (0,), direction: int = 1):
    '''
    step_sizes: The list to be traversed.
    path: Already visited indices.
    direction: Either +1 (right) or -1 (left).
    '''
    step = step_sizes[path[-1]] * direction
    new_pos = path[-1] + step
    if new_pos not in range(len(step_sizes)):  # Out of bounds.
        raise IndexError
    if new_pos in path:  # Contains a cycle.
        raise IndexError
    if new_pos == len(step_sizes) - 1:  # Solution found.
        return path + (new_pos,)
    try:
        return move(step_sizes, path + (new_pos,), -1)  # Move left.
    except IndexError:
        try:
            return move(step_sizes, path + (new_pos,), 1)  # Move right.
        except IndexError:
            if len(path) > 1:
                raise
```

Or by using a wrapper function:

```
def wrapper(step_sizes: list):
    try:
        return move(step_sizes)
    except IndexError:
        return None
```

You can also compute all possible paths by using a generator (borrowing from [@blhsing's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55047591/3767239)):

```
def move(step_sizes: list, path: tuple = (0,), direction: int = 1):
    '''
    step_sizes: The list to be traversed.
    path: Already visited indices.
    direction: Either +1 (right) or -1 (left).
    '''
    step = step_sizes[path[-1]] * direction
    new_pos = path[-1] + step
    if new_pos not in range(len(step_sizes)):  # Out of bounds.
        raise IndexError
    if new_pos in path:  # Contains a cycle.
        raise IndexError
    if new_pos == len(step_sizes) - 1:  # Solution found.
        yield path + (new_pos,)
    try:
        yield from move(step_sizes, path + (new_pos,), -1)  # Move left.
    except IndexError:
        try:
            yield from move(step_sizes, path + (new_pos,), 1)  # Move right.
        except IndexError:
            if len(path) > 1:
                raise
```

Then you can find the shortest path via:

```
min(move([1, 2, 6, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1]), key=len)
```

Comment: Given `move([3,3,3,2,2,2,0],(0,),1)`, this incorrectly returns `None` when it should return `(0, 3, 5, 3, 1, 4, 6)` or `(0, 3, 1, 4, 6)`.